# Pre-populate the correct choice for a CharField in a Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a model which contains a CharField consisting of choices as in the example below

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(choices=(('Name1', 'Name1'),
                                           ('Name2', 'Name2'),
                                           ('Name3', 'Name3')
                                          )
                                 )
```

Here is my ModelForm

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

Here is my basic view which attaches an instance to the form:

```
def some_view(request, model_id):
    somemodel = SomeModel.objects.get(id=model_id)
    form = SomeModelForm(instance=somemodel)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

When the form is rendered the dropdown is not pre-populated. It is not a case of something being wrong with my code as all other form fields (omitted from this example) ARE pre-populated. I know I could make the CharField a ForeignKey and then Django would pre-populate the dropdown correctly but I don't want to do this. Is there any way to make the form show the correct choice? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: As @solarissmoke requested here is how I rendered the form. There's no submit button because I'm using ajax to submit the form as soon as the value is changed.

```
<form action="{% url 'some_location' %}" method="post">
    {{ form.some_field }}
</form>
```

**Comment** Thanks @solarissmoke for prompting me to dig deeper. Django was working just fine. My ajax submission was not set up properly and improper jquery was messing with the choice displayed. Thanks for your response and I apologise for any time you wasted. Phil

Comment: Please show us how you are rendering the form. It almost certainly *is* an issue with your code because Django would populate the field correctly if the instance has a value set for that field.

Comment: @solarissmoke form rendering added above.

Comment: That should render the value... can you show us the rendered HTML that this generates?

Answer (score 2):

I've just worked out a jquery solution but I'd like something more django-like if possible...

```
$("#id_some_field").val("{{ form.some_field.value }}");
```